# Safe way of assigning pixel value

Tags: opencv

Anyone knows how can I assign pixel value in a safe and fast way? Currently I use this,

```
dataTemp[y*stepTemp + x] = 255*constant_value*pow(dataTemp[y*stepTemp + x]/255.0, 1.25);
```

It is possible loss of data (conversion from double to uchar) and I'm afraid the values will go off 255. I'm using C (IplImage). Please help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: use static_cast<uchar>(...) for a safe cast

Comment: Your image is CV_8U ? get pointer to start data, then use a loop `unsigned char *data = image.data`, `unsigned char *dataend = image.data + image.width*image.height`, while (data != dataend) *data++ = 255*constant_value*pow(*data/255.0, 1.25); this will at least save you the computation of the table index...

Comment: @remi, yes the image is gray scale image. you are using c++? Which table are you referring?

Comment: I mean, you just shift the pointer instead of computing y*stepTemp + x to get the index in "dataTemp"

Answer (score 2):

If you have a lot of pixels to convert (looks like a gamma correction), the natural optimization would be to start by computing a lookup table (array of 256 uchars) and then just use it for each pixels.

Comment: @MizukiKai: Either that or just program the array lookup yourself if you don't want to affect the entire image: `dataTemp[y*step+x]=lookupTable[data[Temp[y*step+x]];`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean here Henning.

Comment: @MizukiKai: What is the problem? Note that I accidentally wrote `data[Temp` where I just meant `dataTemp`.

Comment: I want to assign the pixels value with fast and safer way. The code I provided doesn't seem to be good enough isn't it?

Comment: @MizukiKai: The general problem with your code is that it will be slow as molasses because you're doing several transcendental floating-point operations for each pixel (the `pow` function works by doing logarithms and antilogs internally). I'm proposing that you're do those computations once and for all for each of the 256 possible pixel values, and then just look up the precomputed result for each pixel you actually want to transform. Then you can afford to be careful about rounding and overflows while computing the lookup table.

Comment: I see. How can I start doing it? I mean how can I create the look up table?Indeed what I'm doing now is very slow.